# Merging a list into a dictionary and giving it a specific key name python 3

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm using Python 3 to get some values back in the form of a list. These values can be floats, strings, or even `None`. For instance, I can have a list like:

`value = [ None, 1.2, 1.44, 'test', 9 ]`

I have a dictionary that matches the amount of entries in this list, and I want to loop through the dictionary, adding values to this dictionary and giving it a specific key.

So, if my dictionary looks like this:

```
di = [ 
   {'date' : '01/01/2019', 'info' : 'hello' },
   {'date' : '01/02/2019', 'info' : 'world' },
   {'date' : '01/03/2019', 'info' : 'test'  },
   {'date' : '01/04/2019', 'info' : 'no'    },
   {'date' : '01/05/2019', 'info' : 'yes'   }
]
```

I want to iterate over `value` and push each item into a specific key in `di` such that `di` looks like this after:

```
di = [ 
  {'date' : '01/01/2019', 'info' : 'hello', 'update' : 'None' },
  {'date' : '01/02/2019', 'info' : 'world', 'update' : 1.2    },
  {'date' : '01/03/2019', 'info' : 'test',  'update' : 1.44   },
  {'date' : '01/04/2019', 'info' : 'no',    'update' : 'test' },
  {'date' : '01/05/2019', 'info' : 'yes',   'update' : 9      }
]
```

I've looked at some other answers and there were two methods that looked like they were able to do this:

Method 1:

```
for k, *v in value:
    data[k]['update'] += v
```

Returns: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Method 2:

```
for i, v in value:
    data[i]['update'] = v
```

Returns: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

So, this `None` value (which I need) is clearly messing with iterating over values. Is there any way to loop over `value` and append that value to my dictionary using something simple in Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for newval, dic in zip(values, di):
    dic['update'] = newval
```

`zip` is the key to associating each of the values with the dictionary you need to update. It lets the `for` loop take one from each of the two lists.